# Counting undirect graph

Tags: java

Right now I am counting the edges twice since (u,w) and (w,u) is the same.

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
   for (int j = 0; j < graph.length; j++){
     if (isEdge(graph.vertex[i], graph.vertex[j]){ // if u -> w is edge. 
       counter++;
     }
    }
  }
```

How can I make it so that it is not counting the edges twice? I can't think of a simple way, please enlighten me. (There are selfedge too, and I don't want to do counter/2 at the end of loop, edge count can be odd numbers). An self edge is (u,u). I'm not allowed to add any extra fields in the data structure such as "visited". I also tried to make the inner for loop start from int j = i. However, using that method will not detect self edges.

Comment: Mark the edge as visited.

Comment: what are selfedges? a edge from same node to itself? how can there be odd numbers of edges if everything is calculated twice. as i see it, also self-edges are calculated twice

Comment: An self edge is (u,u). I'm not allowed to add any extra fields in the data structure such as "visited".

Answer (score 2):

Make the inner loop start from `i`. When `i=0` all the edges of `node 0` will be visited. So when `i=1` you can skip the values of `j` which are less than `i`

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
     for (int j = i; j < graph.length; j++){
         if (isEdge(graph.vertex[i], graph.vertex[j]){ // if u -> w is edge. 
             counter++;
         }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also tried to make the inner for loop start from int j = i. However, using that method will not detect self edges.

Comment: Why. For each iteration of the outerloop, the inner loop starts at `(i,j)` where `i=j` which will detect self edges

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
               for (int j = 0; j < graph.length; j++){
                 if (isEdge(graph.vertex[i], graph.vertex[j]){ 
                     if(i<j)
                     {
                         if (!isEdge(graph.vertex[i], graph.vertex[j]){ 
                             counter++; 
                         }

                     }else
                     {
                         counter++;
                     }
                 }
                }
              }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < graph.length; i++){
     for (int j = i; j < graph.length; j++){
         if (isEdge(graph.vertex[i], graph.vertex[j]){ // if u -> w is edge. 
             counter++;
         }
         else
         if (isEdge(graph.vertex[j], graph.vertex[i]){ // if w -> u is edge. 
             counter++;
         }
        }
    }
```